# How to add 2 Sliding Menu in Google Material Design Lite

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I need to add two sidebar drawers(left side and right side) for my design using [Google MDL](http://www.getmdl.io/).But mdl layout doesn't support for add two sidebar drawers.How can i do this ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, having two sidebars drawers is a bad idea usability-wise:

You should consider the following options as per the  [Material Design Guidelines on top-level view strategies](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74934/android-ux-when-to-use-tabs-and-when-to-use-navigation-drawer):

1. Focus on a single view with embedded navigation
2. Use tabs to switch between a small number of equally important views
3. Manage more complex structure through a left navigation drawer.

If you have multiple views that would require you to do this, your  better of considering tabs.

See [UX designers: Side drawer navigation could be costing you half your user engagement](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2014/04/08/ux-designers-side-drawer-navigation-costing-half-user-engagement/)

> .....if your app has multiple views that users will engage with somewhat equally, then side navigation could be costing you a great deal of your potential user engagement, and interaction with those part of the app accessed via the side menu.

Comment: I agree with you,But this isn't a mobile application,It's a website.

Comment: Still a bad idea, since you have to toggle them to be seen. e.g. having two footers, which doesn't make sense regardless of the size of content you have

Comment: - 1 This is a bad answer, in fact it is not even an answer but a critic which should have been a comment. See my copy-paste answer below for more info.

Comment: This goes against Google's material design: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1597#issuecomment-140044327. But if you still insist on your two sidebars, be my guest

Comment: So I guess the comment further down the thread by the MDL Devs that 2 drawers are a valid use case and that they are reopening the issue (confirm its not closed) so that its included in 2.x means nothing. https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1597#issuecomment-199394337

Answer (score 0):

Was researching 2 drawers myself when I came across this question. This is possible, and a good design in certain applications and is actually in the roadmap for material design lite version 2. Please read the Github thread here https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1597

There are 2 hosted examples of this in action the best is in use in Rich Media Gallery filter option, that is a Google Material Design Showcase.
http://richmediagallery.com/tools/template-database

The other example is a fiddle